# When you SSH a remote login to another computer can you change permissions on a file or directory? If so how?

Tags: ssh, macos

I SSH a remote login to a computer but found that even with administrator privileges I could not change permissions on a directory I wanted to copy.

I tried `sudo chmod -R 777 directory`

It prompted for a password which i then entered but it said you don't have permission.

This was on Mac Os Unix.

Comment: SIP might be preventing you from changing permissions on system directories.

Comment: I see.  So even logged in as an admin, I am not able to change permissions?

Comment: Be aware that `chmod 777` is never the right way to go in the first place.

Comment: `Mac Os Unix`... that's not really a thing you know.

Comment: Was the directory you wished to copy actually local to the remote computer you SSH’d to, or was it shared from another server or a NAS device? NFS shares often have the “root_squash” option set at the NFS server side, so being root at the NFS client means nothing. SMB (=Windows-style) shares can be restricted by a server-side ACL, or the access might be restricted according to the permissions of the account that was used to mount the share.

Comment: it was on the remote computer